# AJAX not working with Laravel 4

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm not able to use Ajax from a Blade view with jQuery. As I've researched, it just is as simply as using the function `$.get` or `$.post` as usual and taking as first parameter the appropriate root. If I do:

**app/views/home/index.blade.php**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
{{Form::button("d",["id"=>"d"])}}
<script>
    $("#d").on("click",function(){
        $.post("/ajax",function(d){
            console.log("d");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**app/routes.php**

```
Route::post("/",['as'=>'ajax'],function(){
    return 'returned form route';
});
```

I'm always taking a 500 Internal server error, same case if I try with a get request. Also made:

```
$.post("{{{route('ajax')}}}",function(){ ...
```

But also does not work.

I've realized problem is I have an extra http:// at the beginning which shouldn't be there. How could I take appropriate localhost:8000 making it also working on a server?

Also checked Michael Calkins' video [How to submit ajax with Laravel video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myYAQ44yMmo) but I think I've done the same and still not working.

If I write as the route the whole URL (localhost:8000/) I take a security error cross origin request and appart from this, it's clear this is not the best solution.

Comment: 500 means a server error occurred. To work out _what_ error, you should have some logs somewhere. Check either your PHP logs, or something in Laravel if it offers that feature. Or, is there perhaps a debug mode in this framework so you can see errors on screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the details posted it looks like you're doing a GET on a POST route, try changing

```
Route::post("/",['as'=>'ajax'],function(){
```

to

```
Route::post("/ajax", ['as'=>'ajax', function()
{
    // Your code...
}]);
```

or alternatively change the AJAX from a $.get to a POST

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake putting the code here, I've edited it to display how is it, the problem persists. Regards.

Comment: Have you tried changing the route to how I have it? Check where the closure sits, your example has the closure outside of the array and from my knowledge it needs to be in the array, so "Route::post("/",['as'=>'ajax'],function(){" turns into "Route::get("/", ['as'=>'ajax', function(){"

Comment: Just checked the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L145) and it's because the method is called incorrectly, to fix it just move the closure into the array like Route::post("/ajax",['as'=>'ajax', function(){

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem